# How to automate generating an Azure AD Access Token in a PowerBI Embed

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, powerbi-embedded

I have a React app where I'm embedding a PowerBI service report with user-owns-data (aka embed-for-organization) method with the help of powerbi-client-React library. like follow.

```
<PowerBIEmbed
  embedConfig = {{
    type: "report",   // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual and qna
    id: "281839f6-4971-4ad3rtt",
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad
    accessToken : "938orie90rekjd-9393"
     ....some more properties here....
  />
```

where, `models` object is imported from `powerbi-client` library, and `<PowerBiEmbed/>` from 'powerbi-client-react (dependency).

Currently to get that 'azure ad access token' what I'm doing is-

1. Signing into my PowerBI account
2. Going to the browser console, and doing `copy(powerbiaccesstoken)` and I get my token.
3. I go into my code and paste it there.

So, now the report is embedded in my React app for at least 1 hour, because that token is only valid for one hour. Thereafter it shows a prompt for the user to sign in with their PowerBI credentials.

[image: sign into PowerBI popup while embedding report]

Now I have to sign into my PowerBI account again, copy the AAD token, and paste it into my code.

I have a dedicated PowerBI Pro account whose credentials can be used in creating access tokens.

Is there a way for me to do this without copying the token repeatedly? And some JavaScript code on either front-end or back-end do this for me before the access token really expires?

Answer (score 0):

> And some javascript code on either front-end or backend do this for me before the access token really expires?

Yes.  This must be done from the back-end, as you can't expose the master user credentials to the client.  Follow the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core) to get the access token for your master user, and create the embed token from a back-end service.